# Creating a SQL query to sum and divide

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
Username | score | gameid
SimJoo   | 14    | 1
SimJoo   | 20    | 1
SimJoo   | 23    | 2
Master   | 32    | 1
Master   | 25    | 2
Master   | 9     | 2
```

For every player, I need the sum of the highest score of the player at every gameid divided by the highest score gotten for that gameid. This, for any number of different players, scores and gameids.

The result of above example table would be:

```
Username | total score
Master   | 2.000
SimJoo   | 1.545
```

For clarity:

- The calculation for the player master is (32/32)+(25/25) =2.000
- The calculation for the player SimJoo is (20/32)+(23/25) = 1.545

---

```
SELECT Username, SUM((SELECT MAX(score) WHERE Username=? AND gameid=?)/(SELECT MAX(Score) WHERE gameid=?)) AS total_score
GROUP BY Username
ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first subquery returns max score of user per game. The second one - max for games

```
select Username, sum(umax/gmax) 
    from 
      (select Username, gameid, max(score) umax 
          from t
        group by Username, gameid 
     ) u
    left join 
      (select gameid, max(score) gmax 
          from t 
        group by gameid
      ) g
    on u.gameid = g.gameid
  group by Username
```

[example on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf9490/1)

Comment: If you are interested in the thing I use it for, check this: diy-games.com/top100.php. It's a leaderboard for competitive Minecraft Challenges. I'm hoping it to be very popular soon.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, this requires two aggregations and a join:

```
select t.username, sum(t.score / g.maxscore)
from t join
     (select gameid, max(score) as maxscore
      from t
      group by gameid
     ) g
     on t.gameid = g.gameid
group by t.username;
```

Comment: instead of t.score you should use the max of user per game